# How to declare a constructor of template class as friend with clang? (compiles with g++, not clang++)

Tags: c++, clang++

I have a template class with a private constructor which is to be friends of every typed instance of the class. The following compiles under g++ 11.4.0 but fails under clang++ version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1

```
template <typename T>
class foo {
    foo(T){}
    template <typename U> friend foo<U>::foo(U);

    public:
    foo(){}
};

int main() {
    foo<int> a{};
}
```

clang gives the error

```
main.cpp:4:34: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'foo<U>::foo'
    template <typename U> friend foo<U>::foo(U);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                 typename
main.cpp:4:46: error: friends can only be classes or functions
    template <typename U> friend foo<U>::foo(U);
```

I don't think `foo<U>::foo` is a dependent type name, but at any rate adding typename as suggested results in the error

```
main.cpp:4:55: error: friends can only be classes or functions
    template <typename U> friend typename foo<U>::foo(U);
```

Comment: I only upvoted because you are demonstrating a difference between gcc and clang.  But actually you haven't demonstrated impetus for requiring the constructor to be a friend.  Also, what's the difference between `foo<T>::foo(T)` and `foo<U>::foo(U)`?  Most importantly, what code are you hoping to write in the constructor (or elsewhere) that requires it to be a friend?

Comment: It looks like the "missing 'typename'" error goes away in clang 16. It might be a bug in the compiler or maybe an incomplete implementation of the C++20 rules. Do you want to focus your question on the "friends can only be classes or functions" error (which appears whether or not you use `typename`)?

Comment: @JaMiT The english may be imprecise but the code is indeed what I intend by it. Clang's trunk also fails even with -std=c++20 https://godbolt.org/z/xrfrva115

Comment: Did a few more experiments, and the two messages might be related. The "missing 'typename'" error becomes *"missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name foo<U>::foo; implicit 'typename' is a C++20 extension"* in clang 16 if compiled as C++17. Also, if I change the parameter from `U` to `const U&`, clang starts complaining that it expected a semicolon instead of a parameter list. So an underlying issue looks like clang does not see the friend as a function declaration.

Comment: As a potential work around, is there any reason you wouldn't want to make the whole class a friend of itself? As in `template <typename U> friend class foo<U>;`?

Comment: @Eric *"Clang's trunk also fails even with -std=c++20"* -- Yes, but not with the "missing 'typename'" error. Which matches my experiment with clang 16. Which is why I asked if you want to drop the "missing 'typename'" error from the question. Not drop both errors, just the one that was resolved in 16.

Comment: @Eric *"The english may be imprecise"* -- Since you've confirmed the prose is the error, I've corrected the English to match your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a compiler bug in clang. If we look at the related case where the class template constructor being befriended belongs to a different non-template class:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct X {
    X(T);
};
class C {
    template<class U> friend X<U>::X(U);
    C();
};
template<class T> X<T>::X(T) { C c; }
X<int> x(1);
```

This gives a clue to the behavior of clang; which accepts with a warning:

> warning: dependent nested name specifier 'X::' for friend class declaration is not supported; turning off access control for 'C' [-Wunsupported-friend]

So, clang is missing support in this area and doesn't realize it (to at least be able to warn) in the case where the constructor being befriended belongs to a class template.

The simplest workaround is probably to follow the suggestion at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42328#c4 and befriend the whole class:

```cpp
    template <typename U> friend class foo;
```

Comment: @Jarod42 oops, thanks. I think gcc is fine then and we're left with just a bug in clang.